# How to print specific numbers from txt file?

Tags: java

I have a text file written in the following texts:

```
18275440:Annette Nguyen:98 
93840989:Mary Rochetta:87 
23958632:Antoine Yung:79 
23658231:Claire Coin:78 
23967548:Emma Chung:69 
23921664:Jung Kim:98 
23793215:Harry Chiu:98
```

I want to extract last two digit numbers from each line. This is my written code:

```java
for (int i = 3; i < 25; i++) {
    line = inFile.nextLine();
    String[] split = line.split(":");
    System.out.println(split[2]);
}
```

And I am getting a runtime error.

Comment: could you also share the error?

Comment: The loop goes from `i=3` while `i < 25` because.... there are 3 lines of "junk" at the start of the text file, and 25 lines total?

Comment: I don't know which error you are getting?

Comment: Type your error here..

Comment: @Joshua Nguyen, did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Update the reading method, if you are using `Scanner` you can check if there are more lines left or not.

```
while(inFile.hasNextLine()) {
    line = inFile.nextLine();
    String[] split = line.split(":");
    System.out.println(split[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the complexity of the `for` loop specification?  You don't use `i`, so why bother with all that.  Don't you just want to read lines until there aren't any more?  If you do that, assuming that `inFile` will let you read lines from it, your code to actually parse each line and extract the number at the end seems right.  Here's a complete (minus the class definition) example that uses your parsing logic:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Open the input data file
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/data.txt"));

    while(true) {
        // Read the next line
        String line = inFile.readLine();

        // Break out of our loop if we've run out of lines
        if (line == null)
            break;

        // Strip off any whitespace on the beginning and end of the line
        line = line.strip();

        // If the line is empty, skip it
        if (line.isEmpty())
            continue;

        // Parse the line, and print out the third component, the two digit number at the end of the line
        String[] split = line.strip().split(":");
        System.out.println(split[2]);
    }
}
```

If there's a file named `/tmp/data.txt` with the contents you provide in your question, this is the output you get from this code:

```
98
87
79
78
69
98
98
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be so explicit with your loop criteria. Use a counter to acquire the data you want from the file, for example:

```
int lineCounter = 0;
String line;
while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
    line = inFile.nextLine();
    lineCounter++;
    if (lineCounter >=3 && lineCounter <= 24) {
        String[] split = line.trim().split(":");
        System.out.println(split[2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Java 8, you can take a simpler, less imperative approach by using BufferedReader's [lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) method, which returns a Stream:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/data.txt"));
reader.lines()
      .map(line -> line.split(":")[2])
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But, come to think of it, you could avoid BufferedReader by using [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) from Java's NIO API:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("/tmp/data.txt")) 
      .map(line -> line.split(":")[2])
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code gives error. If you had any unwanted lines (I see you have 3 such lines in your code) in the beginning just run an empty scanner over them.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("E:\\file.txt"));

String[] split;
    
// run an empty scanner
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) scanner.nextLine();

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    split = scanner.nextLine().split(":");
    System.out.println(split[2]);
}
```

In case you don't know of such lines and they would not comply to the rules of the lines, then you could use try...catch to eliminate them. I'm using a simple exception here. But you could throw an exception when your conditions doesn't meet.

Suppose your file looks like this:

```
1
2
3
18275440:Annette Nguyen:98 
93840989:Mary Rochetta:87 
23958632:Antoine Yung:79 
bleh bleh bleh
23658231:Claire Coin:78 
23967548:Emma Chung:69 
23921664:Jung Kim:98 
23793215:Harry Chiu:98
```

Then your code would be

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("E:\\file.txt"));

String[] split;

// run an empty scanner
// for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) scanner.nextLine();

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    split = scanner.nextLine().split(":");
    try {
        System.out.println(split[2]);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on `\d+:[\p{L}\s]+:` and take the second element from the resulting array. The regex pattern, `\d+:[\p{L}\s]+:` means a string of digits (`\d+`) followed by a `:` which in turn is followed by a string of any combinations of letters and space which in turn is followed by a `:`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "18275440:Annette Nguyen:98";
        String[] split = line.split("\\d+:[\\p{L}\\s]+:");
        String n = "";
        if (split.length == 2) {
            n = split[1].trim();
        }
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
98
```

Note that `\p{L}` specifies a [letter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).